# Mod_Rewrite Regular Expression Single character not case sensitive

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I moved my files from windows host to linux host.  There is one folder of images that has some links pointing to it with a different case for 1 character of the file name, so they show 404.  I figured this should be easy with mod_rewrite but I can't seem to get it working...

> Original URL: http://www.mydomain.com/v/vspfiles/photos/myimage1-1**t**.jpg
>
> File name: /v/vspfiles/myimage1-1**T**.jpg
>
> Correct Final URL: Original URL: http://www.mydomain.com/v/vspfiles/photos/myimage1-1**T**.jpg

Here's the rule I was trying to make work, but it doesn't seem to work... still get 404.

> RewriteRule  ^(v/vspfiles/photos/)(.)*t.jpg$
>   http://www.mydomain.com/v/vspfiles/photos/$1T.jpg [L]

also tried

> RewriteRule  ^(v/vspfiles/photos/)(.)*t.jpg$
>   http://www.mydomain.com/v/vspfiles/photos/$2T.jpg [L]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing directly "http://" will force a redirection (tell me if I'm wrong on this point but some of my tests gave me this results).

So your solution should be:

```
RewriteRule ^v/vspfiles/photos/(.*)t\.jpg$ /v/vspfiles/photos/$1T.jpg [L]
```

Please tell me if this works.